# LoginWithMicrosoftAccountAsync always fails with 401

Tags: c#, azure-mobile-services, live-sdk

I have created a universal app and an azure mobile services. I followed the tutorial on adding microsoft account authentication as is provided at the azure website. I am using the newest Live SDK for this purpose.

Client side, i am using this code, which is more or less straigt out of the tutorial:

```
const string ReferralUrl = "https://my-url-here.azure-mobile.net/";

static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(
          "https://my-url-here.azure-mobile.net/",
          "my key");

MobileServiceUser _user;

private LiveConnectSession _session;
private async Task Authenticate()
{
    var authClient = new LiveAuthClient(ReferralUrl);
    while (_session == null)
    {
        var result = await authClient.LoginAsync(new[] { "wl.basic" });
        if (result.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
        {
            _session = result.Session;
            var client = new LiveConnectClient(result.Session);
            var meResult = await client.GetAsync("me");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
        }

    _session = null;
}

public async Task<bool> Login()
{
    try
    {
        await Authenticate();
        _user = await MobileService
                .LoginWithMicrosoftAccountAsync(_session.AuthenticationToken);
        }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            //return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The following facts have been verified for this application:

- The store entry has been created
- The store entry has been associated with the universal app (this has been performed for both, win8.1 and wp8.1 projects)
- The store app has the following settings:

  - mobile or desktop: yes
  - jwt: yes
  - security: activated
  - redirection url: is set to https://my-url-here.azure-mobile.net/login/microsoftaccount

At the azure portal, in the identity tab, the client id and secret have been entered and saved. However, there is no package-SID (this is also not mentioned in the tutorial).

I downloaded the service project that is created with the mobile service and added it to my solution. Also, I have added the SetIsHosted(true) flag to the WebApiConfig class. Finally i added the AuthorizeLevel attribute to the TodoItemController and set it to User Level. The service has been successfully published to azure.

When i run my application and call Login, it will result in a 401 exception. It doesnt matter if i run it local or hosted.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature - authentication based on information from a client-side SDK for Microsoft accounts (live SDK) or Facebook - is currently not supported in the .NET backend for mobile services. What the .NET backend supports is either the authentication via the web interface for Microsoft/Facebook/Google/Twitter, or client-side authentication for Azure Active Directory. The support for the feature you want should be implemented in a coming release. You can check out the [Azure Mobile team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/azuremobile) for announcements on when it is live.